# 1st argument in array_push only accepts variable

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

[array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

I have a PHP statement as follow (in a method of a class)

```
array_push(self::USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS, 'cname_username');
```

which gives me error

```
 Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference
```

Then I tried it assigning it to variable and it all worked fine

```
$r = self::USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS;
array_push($r, 'cname_username');
```

My question is why does PHP throws an error in above case?
I have an answer but I am not sure so asked here. The answer is like:

`array_push` does not return the modified array but changes the variable given at argument 1. So change are made at the locations in memory where variable (argument 1) is stored.

If we are passing argument 1 as `self::USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS` then with the same behavior of `array_push` it will try to modify constant  `USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS` of a class which will create mess for developer

Am I right?

Comment: I think the answer is YES

Comment: A *constant* is, by its definition, something that doesn't change. It cannot be passed by reference; variables are passed by reference in order to change their value. Why would you modify `self::USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS` since you declared it as a constant?

Comment: @axiac Yes you are right. Initially I thought `array_push` will return modified array so passed it at 1st argument and then got this error

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: everything depends on the details of your project.

---

You can't modify the value of constants.
And the '$r' variable is not a pointer to 'self::USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS' it is a copy of 'self::USER_BASIC_DETAIL_FIELDS'.
I think than you need a static variable instead of constant in that case.